# Copiar arquivos sem congestionar a rede

Tags: c#

Quando eu entrei na empresa, ela já possuía servidores, uma rede estável e um sistema desenvolvido em Delphi e tudo funcionando na mais perfeita ordem. O backup é realizado manualmente todos os dias em um HD externo.

Recentemente em uma conversa com o proprietário foi sugerido implementar o backup automático com uma outra máquina. até ai tranquilo, desenvolvi um sistema (em c#) para realizar esse backup (SQL Server e Arquivos) para rodar a noite. O problema é que a empresa funciona 24 hrs por dia, e no momento em que começa a copiar os arquivos a rede fica congestionada e os sistema em Delphi não roda (ele acessa o mesmo servidor) e a empresa depende desse sistema para dar continuidade das atividades.

É possível conectar no servidor por uma porta de rede especifica com o c#? como fazer isso?
Alguém tem alguma ideia de como resolver isso?

Segue o código:

```
public void CopiarDirSubDir(string DirOrigem, string DirDestino, bool copiarSubDir)
        {
            var dir = new DirectoryInfo(DirOrigem);
            var dirs = dir.GetDirectories();

            // If the source directory does not exist, throw an exception.
            if (!dir.Exists)
            {
                throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(" Diretório de Origem não existe ou não pode ser encontrado!: " + DirOrigem);
            }
            // If the destination directory does not exist, create it. 
            if (!Directory.Exists(DirDestino))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(DirDestino);
            }
            // Get the file contents of the directory to copy. 
            var files = dir.GetFiles();
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                // Create the path to the new copy of the file.
                var temppath = Path.Combine(DirDestino, file.Name);
                // Copy the file.
                file.CopyTo(temppath, true);
            }
            // If copySubDirs is true, copy the subdirectories.
            if (!copiarSubDir) return;
            foreach (var subdir in dirs)
            {
                // Create the subdirectory. 
                var temppath = Path.Combine(DirDestino, subdir.Name);
                // Copy the subdirectories.
                CopiarDirSubDir(subdir.FullName, temppath, copiarSubDir);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Tem certeza que o problema é a rede e que não é o seu programa que está consumindo todos os recursos computacionais do computador em que está sendo executado (I/O no disco, banco, memória e/ou processamento)?

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesse link https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18243/Bandwidth-throttling

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza acredito que seja a rede por que mesmo se eu copiar manualmente a pasta (que contém aprox. 190 GB) também congestiona e o sistema em Delphi não funciona. Obrigado pela resposta e vou me atentar a esses detalhes....

Comment: @LeandroAngelo obrigado pelo link, vou olhar...

Comment: o.O **190GB** explica muita coisa se você tem uma rede de 100 ou 10Mbps...

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza sim, explica mesmo...  Não manjo muito de rede, mas penso que se talvez eu conseguir deixar o delphi conectando em uma porta e o c# em outra talvez um não atrapalhe o outro... Mas não sei como fazer ou se é possível...